# Android abandonAudioFocus getting NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have 2 sets of Code:

First code:

```
private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
        mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener);
    }
}
```

Second code:

```
private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
    mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener);
}
```

First code is ok but second code get NullPoiterException:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.media.AudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(android.media.AudioManager$OnAudioFocusChangeListener)'
>   on a null object reference

Aren't both codes the same?